# Itertools with if condition

Tags: python, python-itertools

I use the pkg itertools to concatenate 2 lines.

Here, the DF :

[image]

```
result=[]
for i, j in itertools.combinations(df["PORT CODE"], 2):
        result.append(f'{i}_{j}')
        dff=pd.DataFrame(result)
```

In this code, I want to add a condition on an other column. If the service code is the same, we can't concatenate.

The result I have with this condition :

[image]

Thank's for helping !

Comment: What is the condition to concatenate? If Service Code is same for two or more PORT CODE, then concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

Use iterrows instead of the PORT CODE column, as follows:

```
result=[]

for (i, r1), (j, r2) in itertools.combinations(df.iterrows(), 2):
    if r1['SERVICE CODE'] != r2['SERVICE CODE']:
        result.append('{}_{}'.format(r1['PORT CODE'], r2['PORT CODE']))


dff=pd.DataFrame(result)
```

each item in iterrows is a tuple of (row index, row data), which is why we have (i, r1), (j, r2)